# linear particles in particle editor for libgdx

Tags: libgdx, particles

I need to make a particle effect of a firework explosion for libgdx, i need the particles to be lines,  something like this :
[image]

the problem is how do i make the lines rotate so they all point to the center of the explosion i cant find how to achieve this in the particle editor, i can only set a rotation value for all the particles together, anyone know a solution?

Comment: were you able to make this? I need the same ..can you help me out

Comment: If you accomplished doing this, I also need some help :)

Answer (score 0):

The "Aligned" checkbox (in the bottom of the editor) should do what you're trying to achieve.